# Docker won't change VHD location

Tags: docker

So I am running on win10 with Hyper-V.

Docker is currently using a harddrive instance thats stored on my C drive (which is an ssd with very little space) I want it on my sshd which is my D drive.

The following is what I tried and has failed, because it looks like Docker just jumps back to its default every time.

- change is using the docker interface in the advance section (to a copy of the vhdx file in the d drive)
- changing it manually in the hyperv manager by having it migrate the harddrive to a new location

As well as other variations where I restart my computer after doing these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **docker > settings > advanced > change vhd location**. Notice, you should select an empty directory instead of copy the VHD file by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

1. Stop  / Shutdown Docker
2. Copy/Move the existing .vhdx from

> C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx

to

> D:\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx (your preferred ssd location)

3. Edit the Docker *settings.json* file (***%APPDATA%\Docker\settings.json***) and configure

> "MobyVhdPathOverride": "D:\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx"

4. Now start the Docker again - the changes should be in place.

Answer (score 0):

When I was having similar problems in that simply changing the Disk image location path would not stick upon a docker restart; this process worked for me:

1. Create the destination folder, make sure its empty (so no copies of MobyLinuxVM.vhdx)
2. In **Docker>Reset>Restore to factory defaults...** restore your docker to factory defaults
3. In **Docker>Settings>Shared Drives** give the drive( in your case, D) shared access to docker. Hit apply.
4. In **Docker>Settings>Advanced** browse under Disk image location to your destination folder. Hit Apply.

ref: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2063

Answer (score 0):

This is DockerDesktop verison 4.7.1.

Click on the docker icon on the taskbar and go to settings or right click the docker icon on the taskbar and select settings. The window below will popup.
[image]

Navigate to the `Resources` on the left pane and scroll down (if `Disk Image Location` is not in view). Click on `Browse` and select an empty folder of your choice. Click on `Apply and Restart` and Docker Desktop will move the `.vhdx` from `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks` to your select folder.

If Docker Desktop encounters an error, close Docker Desktop and navigate to `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json` and edit the `"dataFolder": "D:\\Hyper-V\\Virtual hard disks\\DockerDesktop",` to your destination folder. Restart Docker Desktop.